# Call non static method from Static method and Bind GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi My Static Method is

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static List<Entity.Report> ChartNavigation(string type, string user, string date)
{


        WebForm2 objForm = new WebForm2();
        objForm.BindCVTrackerForNavigation(user, date);

        List<Entity.Report> listchart = new List<Entity.Report>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Recruitment"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlString = "GetNumberOfCVSentForChartNavigation";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", user.Replace("\"", "")));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", date.Replace("\"", "")));
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Entity.Report obj = new Entity.Report();
                    Utilities.Common.Fill(obj, rdr);
                    listchart.Add(obj);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return listchart;
}
```

And I am calling Non static method from it. My non static method is

```
protected void BindCVTrackerForNavigation(string User,string Date)
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Recruitment"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlString = "GetNumberOfCVSentForNavigation";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", User.Replace("\"", "")));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", Date.Replace("\"", "")));
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter DA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DA1.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
            }
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gvCVTracker.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    gvCVTracker.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

When datasource is apply to `gvCVTracker` it throws error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I dont know what is the problem? Any help would be appriciated.Thanks.

Comment: What is `gvCVTracker`?

Comment: @Andrei It is ID of GridView

Comment: When is this non-static method called? Are you sure the GridView was created by then? Actually try debugging your code, and when the exception is thrown you will be able to see exactly what is null

Comment: When the exception is thrown, you can see the innerexception? Can you post that one?

Comment: @Andrei I have chacked using debugging my code..when non static method is called, grid view is null.

Comment: Then this is the source of the problem. When is this method called?

Comment: @Andrei Find `objForm.BindCVTrackerForNavigation(user, date);` in Static method. From that non static method is called.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Well, long story short - you should not create web forms like that. Wen you call `new WebForm()` controls on it are not created automatically for you, that is why GridView is null. Web forms should only be created by ASP.NET engine.

Comment: @Andrei Then what can i do so that i can bind gridview?

Comment: Very hard to answer not knowing you scenario. Why would you bind a grid view from the WebMethod at all? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44403/discussion-between-prashant16-and-andrei)

Answer (score 0):

You must use Page.LoadControl to create an instance of the WebForm2 for it to also process the initialization of the controls.